# New Point for checkbox not pushing over checkbox in the y direction, C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

In a windows C# form, I am trying to create a grid of checkboxes via the use of code, as the eventual program will allow for dynamic input for width and height. However, the code will not draw my checkboxes in the y direction, only the x direction.

```
    private void begin_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form frm = new Form();
        CheckBox[] chk;
        int height = 10;
        int width = 20;
        chk = new CheckBox[height * width];

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= width; j++)
            {
                chk[count] = new CheckBox();
                chk[count].Name = count.ToString();
                chk[count].Location = new Point(i * 30, j * 30);
                frm.Controls.Add(chk[count]);
                count += 1;
                Console.WriteLine(" i: " + i + " j: " + j + " Count: " + count);
            }
        }
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

At the moment it seems to draw one column of checkboxes, but what I want is a grid of checkboxes.

Comment: Did you have a look at the TableLayoutPanel control?

Comment: @JohannBlais, No, I haven't, I will check it out now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you can only see one column of checkboxes is because they are overlapping with each other (i.e. the checkboxes on the left are too wide and overlap the checkboxes on the right).

Add `chk[count].Width = 20;` in the for-loop and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks! What is this doing? Adding a padding of 20 pixels?

Comment: @Richard he is already assigning a location multiply by `30`. that will automatically leave the 30pxl space on every control initialization. ie. `i*30` = if `i = 5` then it will be `150` instead of 5.

Comment: This is just reducing the width of your checkboxes. By default, the checkbox had a width that was too large and it was covering up the checkboxes drawn on the right so it looked like the other checkboxes weren't there, when in fact they were. Checkboxes have a default width of around 100px but you only spaced them 30px apart, hence your problem.

Comment: @Richard, I see, it seems the default width is 100px because the default normally expects some type of text label to go in the checkbox.text field. Thanks for the help guys, and I will certainly check out a better way to do this too!

Comment: ahh you are right the checkbox is taking default width 104

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned incorrect parameter for `Point` class constructor. `Point(x,y)` constructor have parameters `left` and `top` respectively.

try like this.

```
chk[count].Location = new Point(j * 30, i * 30);
```

But, I would like to prefer to use `DataGridView` instead of doing this complected stuff and assign the column type to `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`. That would be simple and your cursor can easily focus on next cell using keyboard. Even you can assign `DataSource` to your `DataGridView`. Thus, you can store your selected values in the database and retrieve it back.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look into `DataGridView`, unfortunately the issue with my poor implementation remains, nothing is being drawn in the y direction. Even if I move onto 'DataGridView', I want to get this working because it's been baffling me all day. (And then I'll do this properly, honest!) Do you have any idea why the y direction is not having checkboxes drawn to it?

Comment: Have you tried to swap the parameter position between `i` and `j` as i have mentioned in my post?

Comment: Yes I have, it seems to be an issue of overlapping as mentioned by Richard, however I thought that specifying the x,y coordinates would have solved the overlapping issue.